# Displaying termcolor.colored in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, text, colors

I am creating a text based connect four game in python. For the two players I am using `termcolor.colored` for two different game pieces. The game board is a multidimensional numpy array. The problem is that when I assign an element in the numpy array to a color, instead of printing the colored text it prints it in unicode. Is there a fix for this?

My code so far (just to test game mechanics):

```
def connect4():
    import numpy as np
    from termcolor import colored
    red = colored('0', 'red')
    yell = colored('0', 'yellow')
    gb = np.array([[" " for x in range(7)] for x in range(7)]).T
    for x in range(7):
        gb[0][x] = str(x+1)
    while 1:
        print(gb)
        rm = int(input(colored('Red\'s move(row): ', 'red')))
        gb[6][rm-1] = red
        print(gb)
        break
```

Output:

```
[['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']]
Red\'s move(row):  2
[['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']
 [' ' '\x1b' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ' ']]
```

How can I print colored text in an array?

Comment: Why are you using Numpy for this? Numpy can handle strings, but it's designed to speed up arithmetic of arrays. But anyway, that array you created is an an array of single characters, you can't put multi-character strings into its cells. The `'\x1b'` isn't exactly Unicode, it's the ASCII encoding of the Escape character, which is the start of your colour control sequence, the rest of the sequence got cut off.

Comment: Does this print coloured text in your terminal? `for i in range(9): print("\x1b[{}mColour {}".format(30+i, i))`

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using numpy because it makes it easier to compare items in the array especially diagonally. It does print color into the terminal but it doesn't print if it is in the array. Is there any way to print colored text into the array?

Comment: There is, but it's a bit of a hack. It's much better to create your own display function. Numpy's printing facilities are intended to display info to programmers, they aren't really designed to create nice output to display to the user. I'll write a short demo. Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to customize the way Numpy prints arrays by using [`set_printoptions`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) or [`set_string_function`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_string_function.html#numpy.set_string_function). Here's a quick demo of `set_printoptions` that prints 0 in black, 1 in red, and 2 in green. Unfortunately, I can't show the colored output here.

```
import numpy as np

fmt = {'int': lambda i: '\x1b[{}m{}\x1b[0m'.format(30 + i % 8, i)} 

gb = np.array([i%3 for i in range(49)], dtype=np.uint8).reshape(7, 7)
print(gb)
np.set_printoptions(formatter=fmt, linewidth=80)
print(gb)
```

**output**

```
[[0 1 2 0 1 2 0]
 [1 2 0 1 2 0 1]
 [2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 0 1 2 0]
 [1 2 0 1 2 0 1]
 [2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 0 1 2 0]]
[[0 1 2 0 1 2 0]
 [1 2 0 1 2 0 1]
 [2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 0 1 2 0]
 [1 2 0 1 2 0 1]
 [2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 0 1 2 0]]
```

Note that I'm using unsigned 8 bit integer values. This is more efficient than storing strings in Numpy arrays.

A better approach is to create a function that prints the board how we want. In this code, I use 1 and 2 for the two player pieces, an empty board cell contains 0. The display function `show` prints 0 as a `-`, and player pieces as a `*`, with red for player 1 and yellow for player 2.

```
import numpy as np

# Reset color & style to default 
off = '\x1b[0m'
# Set color to red
red = '\x1b[31m'
# Set color to yellow
yel = '\x1b[33m'

# Character for a game piece
piece = '*'
cells = ['-', red + piece + off, yel + piece +  off]

BOARD_SIZE = 7

def make_board():
    return np.zeros((BOARD_SIZE, BOARD_SIZE), dtype=np.uint8)

def show(board):
    print(*range(1, BOARD_SIZE + 1))
    for row in board:
        print(' '.join([cells[u] for u in row]))

def drop(board, player, column):
    """ Drop a piece for the player into the specified column """
    for i in range(BOARD_SIZE):
        if board[i, column]:
            break
    else:
        # Column empty
        i += 1
    if i == 0:
        # Column full
        return False
    board[i - 1, column] = player
    return True

gb = make_board()

# Drop some pieces into the board
# 5 red pieces in column 0
for i in range(5):
    drop(gb, 1, 0)

# 6 yellow pieces in column 2
for i in range(6):
    drop(gb, 2, 2)

# 7 pieces alternating between red & yellow in column 4
for i in range(BOARD_SIZE):
    drop(gb, 1 + i%2, 4)

#print(gb)
show(gb)
```

**output**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
- - - - * - -
- - * - * - -
* - * - * - -
* - * - * - -
* - * - * - -
* - * - * - -
* - * - * - -
```

If you run this code in your terminal it should display in color.